# How can I send integer from arduino to another arduino by FS1000A / XY-MK-5V 433Mhz TX/RX Module (WIFI)?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I'm trying to send and receive some data from arduino to another arduino and I'm using arduino UNO and FS1000A / XY-MK-5V 433Mhz TX/RX Modules. 
For transmitting I use the library `VirtualWire` and It works very well for this code:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
void setup()
{
// Initialize the IO and ISR
vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec
}
void loop()
{
  char msg[7] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','!'};
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, 7);
  vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
  delay(1000);
}
```

I was wondering if I want to send some `string` or `int` data how I can do that. 
I tried to use it for string data but I couldn't because the `Input` of function `vw_send(...)` is char and I couldn't use `int` or `string`.
finally I run this code:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
void setup()
{
// Initialize the IO and ISR
vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec
}
void loop()
{
  char msg[11]="Hello there";
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, 11);
  vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
delay(1000);
}
```

and I could send Hello there !, but I'm looking for the correct way for sending `string` and `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Easy Transfer library.  I haven't used the particular modules you have, however I did successfully use the EasyTransfer library with Ciseco wireless modules.  In essence the EasyTransfer library transmits the data as a structure with the same format on each module.  The structure can contain any data type.

Comment: Would you please give me the link of this library?

Comment: How can I choose the library? there is a lot of library about one subject!

Comment: Hi, just Google Arduino EasyTransfer library that will provide links to the actual library and other various questions / comments / answers.  There is only one EasyTransfer library.  Study the available on line information and I am certain you will achieve your objectives.